# Uploading a file to IBM mainframe server resulting in unreadable file

Tags: c#, ftp

I am uploading file to IBM mainframe server. Once uploaded the data in the file is unreadable and it appears as if it is in zipped format. I am using latest Chilkat FTP2 component to upload the files.

I could upload the same file to our local FTP server and the file is readable on FTP server.
I could upload the same file to IBM mainframe server using command prompt and the file is readable on FTP Server.

I am using Binary transfer mode.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wager that the problem here is an endianness difference. Try converting the file from being little-endian to big-endian before uploading it.